# Is there a way to trigger an oozie workflow on successfull completion of another, WITHOUT using sub_workflow

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have 2 workflows, A and B. workflow B depends on successful completion of A. I do not want to wrap both workflows and define them as sub_workflows in one as this is not scalable. 
What I would like is B to poll or somehow get notified when A completes successfully and then kick off on A completing, on or after it's designated time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your workflow A create a shell action at the very end which will contain a shell script with the oozie command to start the workflow B.

The problem is that the job.properties has to be in the local and you dont know that on which node the shell script will execute.

For that include the creation of job.properties of workflow B in the same shell script. Create it and execute it.

Hope this helps.